# Why is the WebBeans (JSR-299) Conversation Context tied to JSF?

Tags: jsf, seam, jsr299

I am reading through the Public Review Draft of the [Web Beans specification](http://docs.jboss.org/webbeans/spec/PDR/html/) (JSR-299) and I am wondering why it is so 'tightly coupled' to JSF?

Especially the Conversation Context seems only be specified for JSF.

I understand, that it is a goal of WebBeans to integrate JSF and EJB3. But would it not make sense to specify the concept of conversations on a more general level (maybe for Servlets in general and not for a specific web framework)?

Is there any technical reason for this? I think it can hardly be, because Seam (which is some Kind of WebBeans-Prototype) does also support Wicket and provides the concept of conversations.

I think it would be helpful to have a Conversation Scope on Servlet level (injecting of conversation-scoped beans into servlets). In my understanding, this is not the case with the ciurrent specification (see chapter 8.5.4). Or am I misinterpreting something here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this today. The reason why the ConversationScope is JSF based is simply because JSF is *the* standard UI framework for Java EE!

Beside this, most of the JSR-299 containers can provide Conversations for other UI technologies like e.g. Wicket too.

Otoh you can easily create your own Scopes which are even portable.

LieGrue,
strub

Answer (score 1):

I think it's soley down to Gavin King picking JSF as his view technology for Seam and him pushing through the JSR as spec lead.

Clearly conversations go wider - for instance, Spring custom scopes have a facility for providing conversations:

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/Scope.html